# simple php search code not returning and results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a simple php search script to work. It currently captures the data from an html and stores it in $input. The problem is that I keep getting no results from the script below. there are no error messages at all though. I know the database has the exact match data in it, but I keep getting the message from my code below for when there is no data. Is something wrong with my SQL?

```
<?php 
//declaring variable 
$input = $_POST['find']; 
//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
if ($input == "") { 
echo "You forgot to enter a search term"; 
exit; 
} 
//open connection 
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );


//the sql statement 

$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
stories.SID,
stories.story_name,
stories.category,
stories.genre
FROM stories
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID=wp_users.ID
WHERE stories.story_name = '$input' OR stories.genre = '$input'");

$results->execute();
$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//giving names to the fields 
$storyname = $row['story_name']; 
$category = $row['category']; 
$genre = $row['genre']; 

//put the results on the screen 
echo "<b>$storyname</b>"; 
echo "$categoy"; 
echo "$genre<br>"; 

//This counts the number or results – and if there wasn’t any it gives a  
little message explaining that 
$anymatches=$row; 
if ($anymatches == 0) 
{ 
echo "<h3>Results</h3>"; 
echo "<p>Sorry, your search: &quot;" . $input . "&quot; returned zero  
results</p>"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: strings are quoted `news.story_name = $input OR news.genre = $input` and why not bind those, its PDO anyway. to turn on error reporting for PDO add `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );` after the connection line. and you only need `->fetchAll`. remove that next `->fetch()`

Comment: *"there are no error messages"* - Because you're not doing that ^^^  - Plus, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - By the way, you've nothing TO prepare http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements. Just use `query`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: and i don't get this `news.ID=wp_users.ID` why?

Comment: @Ghost *Yeah,* too many *unkowns* ;-)

Comment: string are quoted? What should I change exactly? Not sure what i am missing. Do you mean put quotes around "news.story_name = $input OR news.genre = $input" ?

Comment: @ghost news.ID=wp_users.ID joins two tables on the ID.

Comment: you're pounding the nail using claw side of the hammer instead of its face, you need to properly use prepared statements, that input should be bound instead. here's a good read on how to use them http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Thanks but I don't care about the PDO right now. I know how to bind and such and will do that after. I first want this to just get this script to return results that I know it should. And error reporting is on...no errors. Just no data

Comment: Quote and sanitize your inputs. You've an injection problem and that's why your data's not going in.

Comment: I see you accepted an answer. Probably about what I said ^ `Tic-Tac` the hyphen is an injection character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
news.SID,
news.story_name,
news.genre
FROM stories
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON news.ID=wp_users.ID
WHERE news.story_name = $input OR news.genre = $input");
```

Basically, when writing these queries you need to enclose strings in quotes. Right now, your query would contain

`news.story_name=Five Cats Go Missing`

You need it to be

`news.story_name='Five Cats Go Missing'`

Enclose it in quotes `news.story_name='$input'` and so on.

Comment: makes sense. But now when I use your code and i type a search keyword like Tic-Tac, I get this error:  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Tic' in 'where clause' in

Comment: Can you print out the full query?

Comment: I meant the actual query thats causing the error. With values subbed in.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, since you are using PDO, bind your variables. I believe you are vulnerable to SQL injection at the moment. Second turn on your PDO error message, and PHP error messages if you don't have them on. @Ghost suggested how to turn on your error reporting for PDO, and you can user `<?php error_reporting(-1) ?>` for PHP reporting.

Refer to these links for more details on error reporting:

PHP Error Reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

PDO Error Reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

I also you can check the return value of the `$results->execute();`. If there is nothing wrong with your SQL query statement, that should return `true`, with not it will return `false`, thus there is something wrong with your SQL.

Comment: yes...i know about pdo. for now just looking for answer on how to get this code to return the data searched for. Error reporting has always been on. There were no errors until I just tried Ghosts suggestion above. Now I get this error: But now when I use your code and i type a search keyword like Tic-Tac, I get this error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Tic' in 'where clause'

Comment: Can you update your answer to include your database schema, and the exact error produced? I do not see the error message you are receiving. Your comment seems to have it cut off

Comment: Just updated the post for full code. The database is just table stories with columns ID, SID, story_name, genre, category.

Comment: First comment this out "little message explaining that ", just a simple over site. Second do echo $results->execute(); where it says $results->execute(); and let me know what you get.

Comment: Just did all that. Now I see the number 1. Just a white screen otherwise.

Comment: so i guess that mean return true right? but still no results

Comment: Do a print_r on $row, so basically print_r($row), because I think your $row variable has nothing in it. The "1" indicates that your query succeeded (a "0" would indicate failure/false).

Comment: When i print_r I get see the exact result expected! 1Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [display_name] => user3 [SID] => 21 [story_name] => test456 story [category] => Lyrics [genre] => Hip-Hop ) )    So I guess it is working but just not capturing the variables in the echoes...

Comment: There is your issue. You get no result because the values you want are nested in another array. You will need to do $row[0]['ID'] for example to get the ID value.Use $row[0] instead of $row.

Comment: That's was it! I knew it something silly I was missing. It was that plus Ghost's $input in quotes, so points to you both. Thanks

Comment: Hit the up arrows :), and no problem. In the future, any troubles with queries just echo out your execute, if it returns 1 then the query is good. From there do a print_r on what you fetched.